# Quadratic with integer roots and coefficients in arithmetic progression

Tags: quadratics, arithmetic-progressions

> **Question :** Suppose the quadratic polynomial $p(x)=ax^2 + bx + c~$ has positive coefficients $a, b, c$ in arithmetic progression in that order.If $p(x)=0$ has integer roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then what is the value of $\alpha + \beta + \alpha \beta$ ?

My attempt: I am not aware of any inequality of some sort if it exists, but I could not get far by trying substitutions over these unknown variables.

Comment: It's from KVPY-2016 Aptitude test.Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I got it from the past papers

Comment: I'm sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited the question perfectly as original ( See here : http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/resources/2016_qp_sa.pdf; Question No. 1).Now there is no typo.I guarantee. OP has also confirmed it to be from the same source.

Comment: I know that you know thw answer @Jaideep Khare, why don't you answer? :-P

Comment: @Thelonewolfisbackbaby... No I don't have any solution (I skipped it in KVPY Exam) . Who doesn't want upvotes :D :D.

Comment: I m too trying this question still.. Though kvpy exam was half an year ago.. :-P

Comment: Oops, I should have looked under related questions before answering.  I find 3 duplicates without much work.  Shortly voting to close three of them.  The other 3 are: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068329/a-p-terms-in-a-quadratic-equation?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177485/if-coefficients-of-the-quadratic-equation-are-in-ap-find-alpha-beta-alpha-b?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059951/how-can-i-solve-this-question-on-quadratic-equations-and-arithmetic-progression?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b=a+y$ and $c=a+2y$, then matching coefficients of $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ yields $a+y=-a(\alpha+\beta)$ and $a+2y=a\alpha \beta$.  Subtracting yields $y=a(\alpha\beta+\alpha+\beta)$, and substituting back into the $a+y=\cdots$ equation and dividing by $a$ yields $1+\alpha\beta+\alpha+\beta=-\alpha-\beta,$ which is equivalent to $(2+\alpha)(2+\beta)=3$.  As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers there are a small number of solutions that can be found manually, and only one such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are negative, as is required by positivity of the coefficients: $\{\alpha,\beta\}=\{-5,-3\}$.  Hence $\alpha\beta+\alpha+\beta=7$.

Comment: If we relaxed positivity of the coefficients we would get also $\{\alpha,\beta\}=\{-1,1\}$, hence $\alpha\beta+\alpha+\beta=-1$ in that case.  $x^2+8x+15$ and $x^2-1$ are the only quadratics (up to rescaling all coefficients) with integer roots and coefficients in arithmetic progression with the $x$ coefficient in the middle of the progression.